# Why python scipy cross correlation is not working when padding one of the inputs

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cross-correlation

The scipy cross correlation function is simply not working for a specific 1d array and I cant figure out why. The code below demonstrate the problem, just try it with one trace and than the other.

This question is a bit related to [cross correlation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485321/cross-correlation) and [Python cross-correlation not returning correct shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013166/python-cross-correlation-not-returning-correct-shift)

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def _main():
    """
    trace = np.array([0.00000000000000001, 0.00000000000000002, 0.00000000000000001, 0.00000000000000002, 0.00000000000000001, 0.00000000000000002, 0.00000000000000001, 0.00000000000000002, 0.00000000000000001, 0.00000000000000002, # down the step
                      0.99999999999999998, 0.99999999999999999, 0.99999999999999998, 0.99999999999999999, 0.99999999999999998, 0.99999999999999999, 0.99999999999999998, 0.99999999999999999, 0.99999999999999998, 0.99999999999999999, 0.99999999999999998, # up the step
                      0.00000000000000001, 0.00000000000000002, 0.00000000000000001, 0.00000000000000002, 0.00000000000000001, 0.00000000000000002, 0.00000000000000001, 0.00000000000000002, 0.00000000000000001, 0.00000000000000002]) # down the step
    """
    trace = np.array([0.51231204949426460, 0.47472182808002383, 0.48806029762272723, 0.51352464310119930, 0.58506742537603330, 0.62993314829830390, 0.57657927012749040, 0.55369158834668990, 0.56255864527226200, 0.61576098682569510,
                      0.62955418648769630, 0.64236215760241170, 0.69063835641941580, 0.75073729780384960, 0.86896478361172370, 0.92216712516515690, 0.91329988783884970, 0.92807831604813670, 0.99113300320800610, 0.99999999999999990, 0.91527040506699960, 
                      0.80098377331469030, 0.71723934679539750, 0.68275634764039450, 0.65812563395824950, 0.63250963159524040, 0.59999708953480900, 0.55172083058422660, 0.54975037348965490, 0.57011178351142090, 0.52807534544936740])


    left_padded_trace = np.pad(trace, (10, 0), mode='constant', constant_values=trace.min())
    center_padded_trace = np.pad(trace, (5, 5), mode='constant', constant_values=trace.min())
    right_padded_trace = np.pad(trace, (0, 10), mode='constant', constant_values=trace.min())

    correlation1 = signal.correlate(center_padded_trace, left_padded_trace, mode='full', method='fft')
    correlation2 = signal.correlate(center_padded_trace, center_padded_trace, mode='full', method='fft')
    correlation3 = signal.correlate(center_padded_trace, right_padded_trace, mode='full', method='fft')

    corr_peak_index1 = np.argmax(correlation1)
    corr_max1 = np.max(correlation1)

    corr_peak_index2 = np.argmax(correlation2)
    corr_max2 = np.max(correlation2)

    corr_peak_index3 = np.argmax(correlation3)
    corr_max3 = np.max(correlation3)

    offset1 = corr_peak_index1-(center_padded_trace.size-1)
    offset2 = corr_peak_index2-(center_padded_trace.size-1)
    offset3 = corr_peak_index3-(center_padded_trace.size-1)

    print("Corr1: {}, Corr2: {}, Corr3: {}".format(corr_peak_index1, corr_peak_index2, corr_peak_index3))
    print("Offset1: {}, Offset2: {}, Offset3: {}".format(offset1, offset2, offset3))

    plt.figure(1)

    plt.subplot(311)
    plt.plot(range(0, center_padded_trace.size), center_padded_trace, 'r-',
            range(offset1, left_padded_trace.size+offset1), left_padded_trace, 'b--',
            range(0, correlation1.size), correlation1/corr_max1, 'g-',
            [corr_peak_index1], [1], 'k+')

    plt.subplot(312)
    plt.plot(range(0, center_padded_trace.size), center_padded_trace, 'r-',
            range(offset2, center_padded_trace.size+offset2), center_padded_trace, 'b--',
            range(0, correlation2.size), correlation2/corr_max2, 'g-',
            [corr_peak_index2], [1], 'k+')

    plt.subplot(313)
    plt.plot(range(0, center_padded_trace.size), center_padded_trace, 'r-',
            range(offset3, right_padded_trace.size+offset3), right_padded_trace, 'b--',
            range(0, correlation3.size), correlation3/corr_max3, 'g-',
            [corr_peak_index3], [1], 'k+')

    plt.show()
```

Since the shift added by padding is the same and the only difference is the change on the input trace, the results in terms of shift and alignment from the correlation should be the same but they are not.

For the first trace (more synthetic step) the correlations and offsets are: (1 is the left padded, 2 is the centered and 3 is the right padded)

- Corr1: 35, Corr2: 40, Corr3: 45
- Offset1: -5, Offset2: 0, Offset3: 5

For the second trace (more natural), the

- Corr1: 40, Corr2: 40, Corr3: 40
- Offset1: 0, Offset2: 0, Offset3: 0

Follows the plots:

- Plot for the synthetic trace (first in the code)
  [image: Plot for the synthetic trace]
- Plot for the natural trace (second in the code)
  [image: Plot for the natural trace]

## Solution

See answer and comments from Paul Panzer below.

The problem is with the original code is with the non zero padding.

When shifting the array with non zero values, the cross correlation value gets increasingly higher and the peak gets affected. The following code and images demonstrates this effect:

```py
    trace = np.array([0.51231204949426460, 0.47472182808002383, 0.48806029762272723, 0.51352464310119930, 0.58506742537603330, 0.62993314829830390, 0.57657927012749040, 0.55369158834668990, 0.56255864527226200, 0.61576098682569510, 0.62955418648769630, 0.64236215760241170, 0.69063835641941580, 0.75073729780384960, 0.86896478361172370, 0.92216712516515690, 0.91329988783884970, 0.92807831604813670, 0.99113300320800610, 0.99999999999999990, 0.91527040506699960, 0.80098377331469030, 0.71723934679539750, 0.68275634764039450, 0.65812563395824950, 0.63250963159524040, 0.59999708953480900, 0.55172083058422660, 0.54975037348965490, 0.57011178351142090, 0.52807534544936740])

    for padding_value in np.arange(0, trace.min(), trace.min()/10):
        left_padded_trace = np.pad(trace, (10, 0), mode='constant', constant_values=padding_value)
        center_padded_trace = np.pad(trace, (5, 5), mode='constant', constant_values=padding_value)

        correlation = signal.correlate(center_padded_trace, left_padded_trace, mode='full', method='fft')

        corr_peak_index = np.argmax(correlation)

        plt.figure(2)
        plt.subplot(211)
        plt.title('Left Padded Trace')
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.plot(left_padded_trace)
        plt.subplot(212)
        plt.title('Centered Padded Trace')
        plt.plot(center_padded_trace)

        plt.figure(3)
        plt.plot(range(0, correlation.size), correlation)
        plt.plot([corr_peak_index], [correlation[corr_peak_index]], 'k+')

    plt.show()
```

The results are presented below. One can see that, as the padding value increases, the correlation peak moves to the center.

- Traces with different padding levels, from 0 up to the minimum
  [image]

  - Correlation values and peak
    [image]

Answer (score 2):

The difference is explained by the fact that you are padding with the minimum which is not zero in case of the second trace. As a consequence you cannot expect the peak just to shift with the offset. Instead you get the shifted peak curve plus a triangle that scales with the minimum.

[image: summary]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def _main(offset=0, trace_idx=0):
    trace = [np.array([0.00000000000000001, 0.00000000000000002, 0.00000000000000001, 0.00000000000000002, 0.00000000000000001, 0.00000000000000002, 0.00000000000000001, 0.00000000000000002, 0.00000000000000001, 0.00000000000000002, # down the step
                      0.99999999999999998, 0.99999999999999999, 0.99999999999999998, 0.99999999999999999, 0.99999999999999998, 0.99999999999999999, 0.99999999999999998, 0.99999999999999999, 0.99999999999999998, 0.99999999999999999, 0.99999999999999998, # up the step
                       0.00000000000000001, 0.00000000000000002, 0.00000000000000001, 0.00000000000000002, 0.00000000000000001, 0.00000000000000002, 0.00000000000000001, 0.00000000000000002, 0.00000000000000001, 0.00000000000000002]), # down the step
    np.array([0.51231204949426460, 0.47472182808002383, 0.48806029762272723, 0.51352464310119930, 0.58506742537603330, 0.62993314829830390, 0.57657927012749040, 0.55369158834668990, 0.56255864527226200, 0.61576098682569510,
                      0.62955418648769630, 0.64236215760241170, 0.69063835641941580, 0.75073729780384960, 0.86896478361172370, 0.92216712516515690, 0.91329988783884970, 0.92807831604813670, 0.99113300320800610, 0.99999999999999990, 0.91527040506699960, 
                      0.80098377331469030, 0.71723934679539750, 0.68275634764039450, 0.65812563395824950, 0.63250963159524040, 0.59999708953480900, 0.55172083058422660, 0.54975037348965490, 0.57011178351142090, 0.52807534544936740])][trace_idx]

    trace += offset - trace.min()

    left_padded_trace = np.pad(trace, (10, 0), mode='constant', constant_values=trace.min())
    center_padded_trace = np.pad(trace, (5, 5), mode='constant', constant_values=trace.min())
    right_padded_trace = np.pad(trace, (0, 10), mode='constant', constant_values=trace.min())

    correlation1 = signal.correlate(center_padded_trace, left_padded_trace, mode='full', method='fft')
    correlation2 = signal.correlate(center_padded_trace, center_padded_trace, mode='full', method='fft')
    correlation3 = signal.correlate(center_padded_trace, right_padded_trace, mode='full', method='fft')

    corr_peak_index1 = np.argmax(correlation1)
    corr_max1 = np.max(correlation1)

    corr_peak_index2 = np.argmax(correlation2)
    corr_max2 = np.max(correlation2)

    corr_peak_index3 = np.argmax(correlation3)
    corr_max3 = np.max(correlation3)

    offset1 = corr_peak_index1-(center_padded_trace.size-1)
    offset2 = corr_peak_index2-(center_padded_trace.size-1)
    offset3 = corr_peak_index3-(center_padded_trace.size-1)

    return offset1, offset2, offset3

    print("Corr1: {}, Corr2: {}, Corr3: {}".format(corr_peak_index1, corr_peak_index2, corr_peak_index3))
    print("Offset1: {}, Offset2: {}, Offset3: {}".format(offset1, offset2, offset3))

    plt.figure(1)

    plt.subplot(311)
    plt.plot(range(0, center_padded_trace.size), center_padded_trace, 'r-',
            range(offset1, left_padded_trace.size+offset1), left_padded_trace, 'b--',
            range(0, correlation1.size), correlation1/corr_max1, 'g-',
            [corr_peak_index1], [1], 'k+')

    plt.subplot(312)
    plt.plot(range(0, center_padded_trace.size), center_padded_trace, 'r-',
            range(offset2, center_padded_trace.size+offset2), center_padded_trace, 'b--',
            range(0, correlation2.size), correlation2/corr_max2, 'g-',
            [corr_peak_index2], [1], 'k+')

    plt.subplot(313)
    plt.plot(range(0, center_padded_trace.size), center_padded_trace, 'r-',
            range(offset3, right_padded_trace.size+offset3), right_padded_trace, 'b--',
            range(0, correlation3.size), correlation3/corr_max3, 'g-',
            [corr_peak_index3], [1], 'k+')

    plt.show()


x = np.arange(200)*0.01
y1 = np.array([*map(_main, x)])

y2 = np.array([*map(_main, x, np.ones(x.size,int))])

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.title('synthetic')
plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.legend(('left-shifted input', 'centered input', 'right-shifted input'))
plt.subplot(212)
plt.title('natural')
plt.plot(x,y2)
plt.ylabel('x-offset of result')
plt.xlabel('y-offset')
plt.savefig("summary.png")
```

Comment: Not really. I'm padding with the minimum on both cases. Just tried changing the minimum on the synthetic case to the same value of the minimum on the natural case and the result is the same. For one case it works, for the other don't.

Comment: @FábioLobão make the minimum larger and you'll see. "same value of minimum" doesn't mean anything if the curves on top of that are different.

Comment: I have both traces with the same range (from about 0.47 to about 1) and the same number of points, with the same precision and numerical representation (dtype float64) and still, the results are not consistent. 

Have you tried the code? My guess is that there is something wrong on my platform.

By the way, I'm using Scipy
 - Version: 1.2.1
 - Numpy Version: 1.16.0
 - Python System Version: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=8, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Comment: @FábioLobão as I said matching some arbitrary parameters is meaningless as long as the actual signals are just different. If it helps to convince you I've added a summary plot to the post, showing the x-offsets as a function of the y-offsets, and the qualitative behavior is of course the same at y-offset 0 the x-offsets are preserved, but with growing y-offset the x-offsets will eventually be removed.

Comment: You are right Paul. Although I fail to understand why the "smoothing" of the correlation curve due to the increased value of the padding affects the peak value, that should always remain associated with the shift. My guess is that it is a numerical limitation of the algorithm. I did some additional experiments demonstrating the solution of the problem and will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use mode=valid

```
scipy.signal.correlate(in1, in2, mode='valid', method='auto')
modestr {‘full’, ‘valid’, ‘same’}, optional
```

> A string indicating the size of the output:
>
> full
>   The output is the full discrete linear cross-correlation of the inputs. (Default)
>
> valid
>   The output consists only of those elements that do not rely on the zero-padding. In >‘valid’ mode, either in1 or in2 must be at least as large as the other in every >dimension.
>
> same
>   The output is the same size as in1, centered with respect to the ‘full’ output.

[Signal processing (scipy.signal.correlate)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html#scipy.signal.correlate)

Comment: Using valid does not help. In fact, the code stops working for both cases. I understand that one can not use the option 'valid' for syncing two traces since it will not be able to infer the negative shifts properly.

Comment: Just to complement the previous comment.  According to documentation. 'Valid' mode results is an array with length = [max(M, N) - min(M, N) + 1]. In the case of N and M having the same size, translates to 1. In short you have a single value. For 'same': result length =  max(length(M), length(N)) and you can't use it for syncing because you will not have the correlation values of index smaller than length(M) that translates into the alignment is achieved when the second trace (N) is moved to the left .